# Implementation of Queue is not thread safe

Tags: multithreading, scala

I am trying to implement a thread safe queue using a Semaphore that is enqueued with integers. This is not thread-safe at the moment. What would I have to add in terms of synchronization to the queue to make it thread-safe?

I've tried using synchronized blocks on the Queue, so that only one thread is allowed in the queue at the same time, but this does not seem to work, or I am misusing them. What should I be synchronizing on? I have a separate class that is constantly appending and removing with a maintainer thread.

```
class ThreadSafeQueue {
    var queue = List[Int]()
    val semaphore = new Semaphore(0)

    def append(num: Int): Unit = {
        queue = queue ::: List(num)
        semaphore.release()
    }

    def dequeue(): Int = {
        semaphore.acquire()
        val n = queue.head
        queue = queue.tail
        n
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a `ListBuffer` with `append`/`+=:` and `dequeue`/`remove(0)` instead of a `List`, as it's ridiculously inefficient otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

To be thread-safe, you should place code that accesses the queue in `synchronized` blocks, as shown below.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore

class ThreadSafeQueue {
  var queue = List[Int]()
  val semaphore = new Semaphore(0)

  def append(num: Int): Unit = {
    synchronized {
      queue = queue ::: List(num)
    }
    semaphore.release()
  }

  def dequeue(): Int = {
    semaphore.acquire()
    synchronized {
      val n = queue.head
      queue = queue.tail
      n
    }
  }
}
```

A few notes:

1. With the [Semaphore permits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore-int-) value set to 0, all `acquire()` calls will block until there is a `release()`.
2. In case the `Semaphore permits` value is > 0, method `dequeue` would better be revised to return an `Option[Int]` to cover cases of dequeueing an empty queue.
3. In case there is only a single queue in your application, consider defining ThreadSafeQueue as `object ThreadSafeQueue`.
4. There is an arguably more efficient approach of atomic update using [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) for thread-safety.  See this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834489/which-is-the-difference-between-atomicreference-and-synchronized) for differences between the two approaches.

Comment: 1) It's not possible for `dequeue` to return `None`, is it? That's kind of the point of the class. 2) That's also the point of starting the `Semaphore` at 0; the invariant is that there are exactly as many permits available as elements in the queue. 3) I severely disagree with making an `object ThreadSafeQueue`. Just because there's only one in this context does not mean you should ruin your chances of future reuse. 4) Using `this.synchronized` is a bad idea. It means anyone can deadlock the program by also taking a lock on the queue.

Comment: @HTNW, you're right.  I had the Semaphore permits value > 0 in mind when considering the `None` scenario.  The solution was provided to address OP's question re: using of `synchronized blocks`, but I agree with you that the `synchronized` approach (compared to, say, using of `AtomticReference`) isn't necessarily the best way.  Answer edited.