# Thread safe swap of entire map in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I'm implementing thread-safe *map* in the spring web service.

The map is such like this.

- The map is read simultaneously in thousands of client threads.
- The map's content has to be entirely updated sometimes(about once per hour).

I've chosen [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for thread-safe map, but there was no functionality to simply swap its content with newer one, like `std::map::swap()` in c++.
(I thought that atomic update of the entire content is required for multi-thread environment, maybe I'm wrong)

Is there an alternative map with `swap`?

Any suggestion or reply will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not just point at a new map in those cases? Just remember to make your instance variable volatile so that all threads are looking at the most current map.

Comment: @AminM I didn't think about that. Maybe it is possible in my case, I'll try out.

Comment: AtomicReference is probably better as they recommend below.

Comment: A volatile variable is all you need. An AtomicReference get/set are just volatile get/set. So I would not even bother with an AtomicReference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it isn't necessary to *mutate* the map, just atomically *replacing* it, you could wrap the map in an `AtomicReference` and atomically replace the reference in a single go. The different threads wouldn't keep a reference to the map instance itself, but the surrounding `AtomicReference` instance.

```java
class Example {
    private final AtomicReference<Map<String, String>> mapRef = new AtomicReference<>(someInitialState);

    private void consumerThread() {
        // Get the current version of the map and look up a value from it.
        String value = mapRef.get().get("Hello");
        // Do something with value.
    }

    private void producerThread() {
        // Time to replace the whole map for all threads
        Map<String, String> newMap = calculateNewMap();
        mapRef.set(newMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've read the inner code of `AtomicReference` and realized that `AtomicReference.get()` and `AtomicReference.set()` are just equal to assignment operator (`=`). Are there any differences with simple `=` operator?

Comment: Here is a nice readup on "java atomicreference vs synchronized"   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834489/which-is-the-difference-between-atomicreference-and-synchronized and it agrees that because you want to edit one field then AtomicReference is the better choice. Even better is to make the whole thing immutable, but that does not seem to be an option here.

Comment: @codingmonster, Re, "...equal to assignment operator." Just make sure you understand what is being assigned! A variable, `AtomicReference ar` is itself, a reference to to the `AtomicReference` object, and when you call `ar.set(...)` you are effectively assigning to a `volatile` field of that object. It's like you're writing `ar.value = ...`, not the same as if you were writing `ar = ...`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I meant `ConcurrentHashMap mp; mp = ...`, not `AtomicReference ar; ar =...`. `ar.value` is equal to `mp` when i declare `ar` as `AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>> ar = new AtomicReference<>(mp);`